# RStudio problem with xtable "results=tex"... "object tex not found"

Tags: r, sweave, xtable

I am using the 'compile pdf' button in a .Rnw file in Rstudio, including the following:

```
<<longterm1, results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
print(xtable(longterm), include.rownames=FALSE, floating=FALSE)
@
```

But I receive a pop-up message,

> 'it seems you are using sweave-specific syntax  .... you may need sweave2knitr ... to convert it to knitr'

pdflatex is installed and on my path, so I do not understand what I am doing wrong (I am a latex beginner though). How can I get this to work?

Comment: Whilst not answering the question, to work around the problem I am now creating a file with R code: `print(table_longterm, type='latex', include.rownames=FALSE, file="table_longterm.tex")` and  then using `\input{table_longterm.tex}`

Comment: If RStudio's global options are set up to use ``Sweave`` when you intend to use ``KnitR``, you may get error messages and ``\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}`` inserted into your document, which will then interfere with your ability to use ``KnitR`` even after you've changed RStudio's options to use ``KnitR``.  If you see what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

Use instead `results='asis'`:

> `asis`: output as-is, i.e., write raw results from R into the output document.

If you switch from Sweave to knitr, you probably need to read this page: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/